# express angular single page app archetecture

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, sails.js

Hi i am a beginner to *nodejs* & *angularjs*.

I have a requirement for an angularjs application, i am planing to do the back end REST API's using *expressjs*.

For my application I have two parts; one front end UI for general users & one admin panel or managing the entire application database.

I found a number of *angular-express* seed projects on github.

So my question is that which one is the best choice for me among the following :

**1.** Doing a single app using express+angular(is it possible to create a separate area for admin)
**2.** Implement a middleware for REST API's and admin panel using node. Then do a separate angular-seed project.Host the two app separately.

Another question is that whether I should use express or sails js?

Anyone please can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're new to AngularJS i'd strongly recommend starting from nothing so that you get an overall look at how everything comes together, my personal experience is that it's better to use seed projects or generators should once you have a basic understanding of how an AngularJS and nodeJS project comes together

Technically both option one and two are valid however I would go with option one, this means you can build authentication and authorisation into your application and use that to stop people accessing the admin section - This reduces complexity because you don't have to manage multiple projects and may also benefit you personally as it allows you to dive into security and expand your knowledge.

Should you use express or sails? That comes down to exactly what you're building - each library has it's own pros and cons, i'd say it's down to you to weigh up these pros and cons and make a decision on what library you would like to go with.

Comment: thanks Grant.I am building an app it is so similar to soundcloud.So what is your advise regarding express or sails?

Comment: Sails does a lot of the work for you, i.e setting up an applications is easy with scaffolding -- this is useful if you're a developer who already uses nodejs or understands how the application comes together. Sails is also built on top of express so it's basically express with extra features. I would personally use express though if I was yourself given the fact that express will give you a good base of knowledge to start with considering the fact you're new to nodejs, after you get to grips with express i'd have a go at something like sails

Answer (score 0):

You can use app generators. One of the best generator is [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/)
And here [Yeoman generators](http://yeoman.io/generators/) you can query the generator you want